# You will vs you must

Tags: word-usage, differences, north-american-english

With it being a direct order with out a choice. 
Is it written 
You will pay for your sins. 
Or 
You must pay for your sins.

Will seems stronger as You will no matter what. 
Where you must just seems. Weak

Which is correct. I’m reading will is with choice where must is an obligation. So what’s the difference when it’s written as a command

Comment: If it's a direct order, shouldn't it in the imperative: "pay for your sins"? To me, "you will pay for your sins" sounds like a prediction (not an order), something like "I will take revenge on you" or "karma will rectify this injustice."

Comment: I believe "you will" is standard phraseology for military orders (despite its being the merely ordinary second-person future, as opposed to the more emphatic "you shall"). But both your examples here, as @PeterShor observes, seem more like predictions, or even threats or promises, than like orders.

Comment: So if it was an order, you must clean your room. Vs you will clean your room. The will comes off as a threat?

Comment: In some contexts _you will_ could be an order, as Brian says, but  in ordinary life I see it more as a warning that a previous request/order must be carried out. "You _will_ clean your room as you promised or I won't take you swimming tomorrow." _You must_ could be either an order or a warning that circumstances make an action necessary. "You must put your bike in the shed because it is going to rain."

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Do read the FAQ here: english.stackexchange.com/help/asking Good Luck.

Comment: Look up the words in a good dictionary and compare their meanings and usages. See also: [ell.se]

Comment: All modals have different senses. (a) 'An object at rest must stay at rest unless an applied [net] force is applied to it.' circumstantial/root modality: here, actual  inevitability. // (b) 'United _must_ finish in the top half of the league this year (mustn't they?)' epistemic modality: here, what you consider virtually inevitable. //  (c) 'You must stay in tonight because you were out too late last night!' deontic modality: don't even think about going out. _Obey_! // Here, from the context (Who it is who's speaking), it's either (a) or (c). And both apply (though there is a Way out).

Comment: Depends on who's saying it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As has been said - in most contexts, "will" indicates a prediction:  "You will pay for your sins" =  "At some future time, you will pay for your sins" The speaker does not explain how or when this will happen.

Must carries an obligation and also usually refers to something that should be done now or in a very short time:

"You must pay for your sins"-> "You have no choice other than to pay for your sins." The speaker is likely to know what the punishment will be, and the punishment is written down somewhere.

However, depending on the precise context, other answers could be given.

Comment: Do read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/answering Good Luck.

Answer (score -2):

Ok. I figured it out. They’re nearly identical when used in that sentence but will is future tense where must is logically to happen whenever . Nearly the same meaning in this sentence just present vs future.